# How to run another rscript using a button on another script in SHINY

Tags: r, shiny

How to run a code of an R script by clicking the actionButton in SHINY? The button would call the script saved in the same directory and run the script and i want to display the script name to be displayed in the URL.

Please help me out with this. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You can use the `source` function to run an external R script file. Just put a call to `source` into an `observeEvent` tied to the action button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@divibisan basically said it all in his comment. When you want to run a R script, you can use the command source as in

```
source("path/to/my/script.R")
```

All relative paths will be resolved based on your working directory (`getwd()`). If you have a shiny app and a script file (`script.R`) in the same directory, you can use

```
## file: app.R
shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    actionButton("buttonId", "run script")
  ),
  function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$buttonId, {
      message("running script.R")
      source("script.R")
    })
  }
)
```

Then you run the app with

```
shiny::runApp("app.R")
```

or you just use the "run app" button in RStudio.

I dont't really get what you mean with "display the script name". You just include it in the ui?

Comment: Dear @Gregor de Cillia, appreciate if you  could help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59129562/in-r-shiny-how-to-fix-error-in-sourcing-app-as-nothing-changes-when-clicking-on